# Remove files tracked by Git

Tags: git

I'm working on cleaning up my local dev copy.  I have a WordPress installation on the server, but I don't need any of the WP core files in the repo.  I added `wp-*.php` to the local .gitignore, and removed some files using `git rm --cached wp-*.php`.  I committed the changes, and pushed to the central repo.

On the production server, I went to pull the changes with `git pull remote master` and it deleted the `wp-*.php` files from the server.

What is the correct way to accomplish this, without a git pull deleting files from the production server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will only remove them once (because you told Git to remove the files from its tracking). You can then manually add them back on the server side, and Git won't remove them again, because it will no longer be tracking them after the first removal.

Comment: Is there a workaround or some workflow that could allow a working copy to delete some files, and remove them from the index without resulting in a deletion of those files if anyone does a git pull?

Comment: No. If you remove them from the index and commit that removal, Git will treat it as a deletion (which it is) and faithfully remove them when that deletion is pulled. If you want to remove things from being tracked, but keep them around, you need to inform whoever's going to be pulling the changes to back them up before pulling and then restore them again.

Comment: @Amber maybe remove them on another branch '`develop`', and merge that '`develop`' to `master` with a '`--ours`' in order to record the merge without propagating the deletion?

Comment: @VonC That would only result in Git tracking the files again as soon as Poe switched back to master or merged in changes from master. Not a very good long term solution.

Comment: Since it matters most on the production server retaining the untracked files, I'm going to make the changes there when I need to remove some files from tracking.  For my purposes, it's fine if a pull from a dev machine results in file deletions.

Answer (score 2):

@Amber is right that a delete on the repo is a delete, and all clones will faithfully delete those files when they pull the 'git rm' commit. They're sort of re-playing the transactions they're pulling.

If you don't mind keeping the files in the repo, an alternative to removing them would be to just stop tracking their changes. This can be achieved with `git update-index --assume-unchanged`.